# Java(Bukkit) Netty Client stops working when started in second thread

Tags: java, netty, bukkit

I ran into a problem while developing my software.

I have one Netty server and multiple Netty clients. However, when i try to start them in a new thread, they stop after a little debug message. The Client runs on Bukkit, a Minecraft Server Software. The other clients for the other stuff runs on a standalone java program and they work just fine.

This is my client class:

```
public class NettyClient extends Thread {

public boolean connected;


/**
 * Returns true if the client is connected.
 *
 * @return boolean
 */

String host;
int port;
public Channel channel;
public BlockingQueue<Packet> queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();


public NettyClient(String host, int port) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    boolean epoll = Epoll.isAvailable();
    System.out.println("[Sys] Server-Typ: " + (epoll ? "Epoll" : "Nio"));
    EventLoopGroup mainEventLoopGroup = epoll ? new EpollEventLoopGroup() : new NioEventLoopGroup();

    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();


    try {
        bootstrap.group(mainEventLoopGroup)
                .channel(epoll ? EpollSocketChannel.class : NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(final SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new PacketEncoder());
                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("decoder", new PacketDecoder());
                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("wrapperhandler", new WrapperHandler());
                    }
                });
        ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.connect(host, port).channel().closeFuture().syncUninterruptibly();
        this.channel = f.channel();
        System.out.println("Succesfully established connection to the wrapper server!");
       channel.writeAndFlush(new PacketServerLogIn(System.getProperty("servername"),System.getProperty("servergroup"), Bukkit.getServer().getIp(),Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size(),Bukkit.getMaxPlayers(),ServerState.WAITING));
      RedisBuilder.getInstance().startUpdateScheduler();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        mainEventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();

    }
}




public String getHost() {
    return host;
}

public int getPort() {
    return port;
}

public Channel getChannel() {
    return channel;
}
public boolean isConnected() {
    return connected;
}
```

}

And this is my server:

public class NetworkServer {

```
String host;
int port;

public NetworkServer(String host, int port) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
}


public void run() {
    boolean epoll = Epoll.isAvailable();
    System.out.println("[Sys] Server-Typ: " + (epoll ? "Epoll" : "Nio"));
    EventLoopGroup mainEventLoopGroup = epoll ? new EpollEventLoopGroup(2) : new NioEventLoopGroup(2);
    EventLoopGroup workerEventLoopGroup = epoll ? new EpollEventLoopGroup(2) : new NioEventLoopGroup(2);
    ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();

    try {
        serverBootstrap.group(mainEventLoopGroup, workerEventLoopGroup)
                .channel(epoll ? EpollServerSocketChannel.class : NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(final SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLFactory.createAndInitSSLContext("client.jks");
                        final SSLEngine sslEngine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
                        sslEngine.setUseClientMode(false);
                        sslEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslContext.getSocketFactory().getSupportedCipherSuites());

                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(sslEngine));
                        //  socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibEncoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));
                        //socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibDecoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));
                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("decoder", new PacketDecoder());
                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new PacketEncoder());
                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("wrapperhandler", new WrapperHandler());
                    }
                });
        serverBootstrap.bind(port).channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        mainEventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerEventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}


public String getHost() {
    return host;
}

public int getPort() {
    return port;
}
```

}

I think Bukkit does not like multiple threads, but correct me if I'm wrong.

My Netty version is: 4.1.2.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all people who also got this error: I found the solution.

You need to use maven in order to compile the right Netty version.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>io.netty</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>io.nettynew</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                </relocations>
            </configuration>
            <executions>

                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This reshades the right netty version into your final jar and you now can connect to another netty server without any problems. Make sure you added the Netty dependency to maven:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.netty</groupId>
<artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
<version>4.1.29.Final</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused because your are calling `.shutdownGracefully();`, this basicly says to the Netty threads & channels that they should shutdown.

Since you are developing a BUkkit plugin, you should call those methods only inside the `onDisable()` part of your plugin.